# How can I maintain linear independence through a commutator?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras, noncommutative-algebra

Consider a Lie algebra $\mathcal{L}$, a linearly independent generating set $\mathcal{G}$, and an element $X \in \mathcal{L}$.

Edit: Note that $\mathcal{G}$ is not necessarily a basis; the generation is via the Lie bracket.

> What are the conditions on $X$ such that $\{[X,g_i]\; \big| \; g_i \in \mathcal{G}\}$ is also linearly independent?

Or is the question too general and the answer must depend on $\mathcal{G}$? In my specific case I am looking at the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})$ if that helps. Also maybe there is a more general answer for any given set of matrices but this is my specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\mathcal{G}$ is a basis, we can write $X\neq 0$ as a non-trivial linear combination of elements of $\mathcal{G}$. Then $ad(X)(\mathcal{G})=\{[X,g_i] \mid g_i\in \mathcal{G}\}$ represents $0=[X,X]$ also non-trivially. Hence this set cannot be linearly independent. In formulas: if $X=a_1g_1+\cdots +a_ng_n$, where not all $a_i=0$, then
\begin{align*}
a_1[X,g_1]+\cdots a_n[X,g_n] & = [X,a_1g_1+\cdots +a_ng_n]\\
 & = [X,X]\\
 & = 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: If "generating" in the question means generating as a vector space, then this answer completely settles the matter.  It's possible, though, that Matta intended "generating" to mean generating as a Lie algebra, i.e., that the elements of $\mathcal G$ and their iterated commutators span $\mathcal L$ as a vector space.  In that case, the answer will depend on the details of $\mathcal L$ and $\mathcal G$ and $X$.

Comment: I did intend $\mathcal{G}$ to be a generating set for the Lie algebra, but thank you very much for the work Dietrich Burde. I can remove the $\mathcal{L}$ ambiguity by saying that it is $\mathfrak{sp}(2n,\mathbb{R})$ but cannot remove any ambiguity in $\mathcal{G}$. I felt like there might be some magical $X$s lying around that had no effect on linear independence but my hope was fairly tentative.